# If $G$ is a directed and finite graph whose underlying graph is a clique, then does $G$ have a root?

Tags: graph-theory

Since I have failed to prove the following I think it's mostly false.

> Let $G$ be a directed and finite graph such that its underlying graph is a Clique.
>
> Then, $G$ has a root.

Can someone give a contrary example?

---

**Note:**

**Finite Graph** means that the number of the graph's vertices and edges is finite.

$v$ is called a **root** of the graph if there is a path from $v$ to every node in the graph.

Comment: What's wrong with my question, If I'm told to prove something or give a contrary example, then if I have no clue I try to prove it If I fail I try to search for example....

Comment: Maybe I'm out of the loop, but I've seen a lot of graph theory and have never seen the terms "final graph" or the "root" of a graph. Maybe start by explaining what you mean there?

Comment: @Casteels Updated my question, Thanks for letting me know

Comment: In that case I presume you mean a "finite" graph?

Comment: @D.A. right, corrected that as well.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what to make of this. As far as I know, an "underlying graph" is only defined for digraphs (directed graphs) and it is the graph you get when you make all edges undirected. But in your case, all edges are alredy undirected. Do you use another definition for "underlying graph"?

Comment: @clark979m I think you meant to write: "Let $G$ be a directed and finite graph ..."

Comment: Sorry Again! I made a mistake and corrected it, I don't know what's going on with me today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think the statement is true. We will proceed by induction over the number of vertices $n$.

Base Case $n = 1$: Clearly the unique vertex in any graph with one node is a root.

Step Case $n \rightarrow n + 1$: Assume as induction hypothesis (IH) that the statement holds for all graphs with $n$ vertices. Now let $G$ be an arbitrary directed graph on $n + 1$ vertices such that the underlying graph of $G$ is a clique. Let $v$ be an arbitrary vertex in $G$ and consider the graph $G' = G - v$ we get by deleting $v$: It is a directed graph on $n$ vertices whose underlying graph is a clique. Hence by IH we know that there exists a root $u$ in $G'$. Now consider the edges incident to $v$ in $G$. If there exists an incoming edge to $v$ in $G$ then $u$ is also a root in $G$. On the other hand, if there does not exist an incoming edge to $v$ in $G$ then $v$ is a root in $G$ because it has an outgoing edge to all other nodes in the graph. Thus there always exists a root in $G$.

Comment: In fact it is not too hard to refine this induction to show that every tournament graph has a Hamilton path.  Of course the front of such a path is automatically a root.